# Adding a variable offset to a signal

Tags: sensor, adc, pwm, offset

I would like to add an offset to a signal to send it on a differential ADC. But i want to be able to control the value of this offset with a PWM. 
My sensor has a bandwidth of [1-100Hz] and i only have a 0-5V supply.

It works well with offset of 2.5V / 2V / 1V but for 0.512V i have an offset of 4V instead at output. And i don't understand why.

The OP-Amp use is a TL072, maybe it's a limit of that Op-Amp?

If you guys have an idea about how i can fix that or which Op-Amp should i use or an another way to doing that i'll like to hear that !

Thank you [image: ![enter image description here]

File:

https://www.catupload.com/download/c5e9aaaa13797a98368cb01dce96e3f5.html

Schematic V2 :

[image]

Comment: Can you also share the simulation file so that we can test the same on our end.

Comment: is that what you asking for? (the link at the end of my post)

Comment: Hint: What are the specs of TL072 with +5 and 0 V supplies?

Comment: @bouaaah I was asking for *.asc file that you used to simulate the schematic in LTspice

Comment: I modified the link, there is the .asc file ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input common mode range of a TL072 doesn't get to within 0.5 volts of the most negative power rail (0 volts) in your circuit. That is your likely problem. Try looking for a rail to rail opamp or maybe try an LM324.

Additionally, the minimum recommended supply voltage for that opamp is +/- 5 volts.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with common mode. I'll try another OPamp asap.

Comment: How did it go with the replacement and what device did you choose?

Comment: I think i'll choose a TLV2252. what do you think about it? And do you know a website where i can learn more about common mode range? Because i don't know how to use the datasheet to choose my opamp.

Comment: The TLV2232 looks OK providing the input voltage doesn't go above 4.2 volts. I'm sure there are websites for learning but I can't particularly recommend any for this other than just trawling thru google with key words. I learnt all this stuff before the internet was conceived so I'm not likely to have used websites for this LOL.

Comment: Hahah ok ty ! But i did a mistake, i mean i chose the TL2369, but i was reading the TL2252 when i respond to your comment  :p

Comment: The TL2369 doesn't come up as a chip on google.

Comment: Wow i was very tired 2 days ago ! So many opamp reference mix into my mind :p I choose the OPA2344

Comment: It's a nice op-amp but could still lose 400 mV on the rails if you load the output too much. You always have to watch out for these things with a lot of R2R op-amps. For instance your sensor output voltage could easily cause a problem.

Comment: Yeah i saw it, but this opamp could lose 400mV under 5kOhm and 1mV under 100kOhms, so i decide to increase the resistance to 200kohms and adding a buffer between sensor and ADC. I'm adding the new version of my schematic on my original post.